# How can i enable/disable a button in a backgroundworker DoWork event?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this method:

```
private void CreateDriversList()
        {
            try
            {
                StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(contentDirectory + "\\" + "Drivers.txt");
                w.WriteLine("Module Name            Display Name           " + "             " + "                                        Driver Type");
                w.WriteLine("===========            ============ " + "             " + "                                                  ===========");
                System.Management.SelectQuery query = new System.Management.SelectQuery("Win32_SystemDriver");
                System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
                foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject ManageObject in searcher.Get())
                {
                    w.WriteLine("{0,-22} {1,-75} {2}", ManageObject["Namedfgfdg"], ManageObject["DisplayName"], ManageObject["ServiceType"]);
                    driversListNumbers += 1;
                }
                w.Close();
                Logger.Write("***** Drivers Text File Have Been Created *****");
            }
            catch(Exception err)
            {
                Logger.Write("There was an exception" + Environment.NewLine + err);
                SendEmail.Enabled = true;
            }

        }
```

This method is called from the DoWork event and when i run my program im getting exception:

Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'SendEmail' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'SendEmail' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnEnabledChanged(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.OnEnabledChanged(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.set_Enabled(Boolean value)
       at Diagnostic_Tool_Blue_Screen.Form1.CreateDriversList() in d:\C-Sharp\Diagnostic Tool Blue Screen\Diagnostic Tool Blue Screen\Diagnostic Tool Blue Screen\Form1.cs:line 135
       at Diagnostic_Tool_Blue_Screen.Form1.backgroundWorker1_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) in d:\C-Sharp\Diagnostic Tool Blue Screen\Diagnostic Tool Blue Screen\Diagnostic Tool Blue Screen\Form1.cs:line 177
       at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
       at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Use Dispatcher for it, but use google next time, it's easy to find

Comment: Is this WPF or Windows Forms application?

From the error it looks like Windows Forms so you'll need to use the old InvokeRequired check or use the BackgroundWork report progress.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Worker threads should never touch the UI. Use `BeginInvoke` instead:

```
SendEmail.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate() { SendEmail.Enabled = true; });
```

Comment: rodrigo tried your solution but im getting an error now: Error 1 Cannot convert anonymous method to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: @DanielVest `SendEmail.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>{SendEmail.Enabled = true;}));`

Comment: @DanielVest: Yeah, the thing is that `BeginInvoke` takes a `System.Delegate`, and curiously enough, that's not a delegate type. So either you use an already existing delegate type (such as `Action`, see my updated answer or @KingKing comment) or you create your own.

Answer (score 2):

Your options are

callig and handling the OnRunWorkerCompleted event of the WorkerProcess -http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker_methods.aspx

or using checking if the invoke is required then using Invoke on the control -http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. Controls reside on the UI thread, and you are trying to modify a control from another thread, which is not possible. You would have to return the result to your UI thread, and take the appropriate action on the control from there.