# Button.Enabled not working on first of several buttons in BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, button, backgroundworker

I have several buttons that I want turned off/on at different times. I put these into a function for simplicity. Enabling the buttons is called by a BackgroundWorker so that I can update a camera view at the same time as listening to a Serial port for an 'enable' signal. Disabling the controls is called by the button click, while enable is handled by the BackgroundWorker (it watches for the Serial port signal). All buttons re-enable, except for the first one listed in enableControls();. If I change the order of enableControls() then the button at top is left disabled. What is causing this? I would think that either all buttons or no buttons would be re-enabled.

```
private void btnLeft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // All buttons are similar, just different output to port
{
    disableControls();
    hardWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    int stepSize = Convert.ToInt32(ddStepSize.Text);
    string outString;
    if (moveSampHome == false)
    { 
        outString = "#MOVER" + stepSize;
        posX = posX - RcDrawSlide.Width * stepSize / (1000 * Convert.ToInt32(slideSizeX));
    }
    else { outString = "#MSMPR" + stepSize; }
    port.Write(outString + "\n");
}

private void hardWorker_DoWork(object sender2, DoWorkEventArgs f)
{
    arduinoIn = "0";
    for (int i = 0; i == 0;)
    {
        if (arduinoIn != null)
        {
            if (arduinoIn.Contains("1"))
            {
                i = 1;
                arduinoIn = "0";
            }
        }
    }
    port.Write("1");
}

private void hardWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    enableControls();
}

private void enableControls()
{
    btnBack.Enabled = true;  // Swap this for any other button - that one will not be enabled.
    btnForward.Enabled = true;
    btnLeft.Enabled = true;
    btnRight.Enabled = true;
}

private void disableControls()
{
    btnBack.Enabled = false;
    btnForward.Enabled = false;
    btnLeft.Enabled = false;
    btnRight.Enabled = false;
}
```

If I add a button that runs enableControls() on click everything is reenabled, so I know this is due to having it run from a BackgroundWorker. I think that BackgroundWorker is necessary, though. I'm just unsure why it's only the first btn.Enabled = true; that doesn't work. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013720/how-can-i-enable-disable-a-button-in-a-backgroundworker-dowork-event

Answer (score 0):

For `hardWorker_DoWork()` try something more like:

```
private void hardWorker_DoWork(object sender2, DoWorkEventArgs f)
{
    arduinoIn = "0";
    while (arduino == null || !arduinoIn.Contains("1")) {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(0); // or try a SMALL number like 50!
    }
    arduinoIn = "0";
    port.Write("1");
}
```

Is it possible the buttons are being enabled again when data is received on the port? You haven't shown any code relating to that side...

Comment: I tried to include only the portions of code that pertained to button enabling/disabling and the process leading up to it. I debated on that knowing I'd get people wondering where the code was in it's entirety, but it's 1000 lines and that seemed a bit much to make people read. Data received is handled by:

`public void Read()
{
    while (port.IsOpen)
    {
        if (port.BytesToRead > 0)
        {
            arduinoIn = port.ReadLine();
        }
    } 
}`
I tried ctrl-f for any missed .Enabled or enableControls() elsewhere in the code but there weren't any.